# PlayFramework with Scala, WebJars, ReactJS and RequireJS?

Tags: scala, playframework, requirejs, reactjs, webjars

I am looking for an example about combining the four technologies in the title :) I have a working ReactJS application using Play, Scala and WebJars, it's [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ticofab/play-scala-webjars-react).

Now I would like to add RequireJS, but I'm not sure how to go, especially because it seems to require a different JSXTransformer? If anybody has a pointer (or even a PR) it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the easiest thing to do, but I was able to pull it off. I will give you some tips here. I also uploaded [my own project to github](https://github.com/miciek/web-snake-react-bacon/tree/play-framework-based). This is a very simple snake game built using React and RequireJs. It based on Webjars and Play Framework.

Remember that RequireJs is part of Play Framework. Here's a step by step guide to create React/RequireJs/WebJars/Play integration:

1. In your plugins.sbt add `addSbtPlugin("com.github.ddispaltro" % "sbt-reactjs" % "0.5.2")`. This is a plugin which transforms JSXes into JSes and also strips flow types if you want that.
2. In your main scala.html file add `@helper.requireJs(core = routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("require.js")).url, module = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main").url)`. This will add add a `script` tag with `data-main` and `src` attributes that are used to bootstrap your RequireJs app.
3. Create `react.js` file in your `assets/javascripts` folder:

   ```
   define(['../lib/react/react-with-addons'], function(React) {
       window.React = React;
       return React;
   });
   ```
4. Create `main.jsx` file in your `assets/javascripts` folder:

   ```
   require.config({
      // standard requirejs config here
   });

   require(['react', 'components/YourComponent'], function(React, YourComponent) {
       'use strict';
       $(document).ready(function() {
           React.render(<YourComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
       });
   });
   ```
5. Your standard React component goes to `assets/javascripts/components/YourComponent.jsx` and is defined like standard RequireJs module. Remember to return a React class:

   ```
   define(function(require) {
       var React = require('react');
       var AnotherComponent = require('components/AnotherComponent');
       return React.createClass({ ... });
   }
   ```

I hope that helps. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Neat. Mind me asking, do you have any thought on sever-side rendering with all these stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Someone said to have got the text plugin working with `sbt-rjs`: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/F789ZzTOthc

I would attempt with the text plugin first, as it's the simplest plugin of all, right? Once this is successful, move on to the JSX plugin:

https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin

Comment: BTW, I prefer Browserify or Webpack over RequireJS, in a separate Gulp-based project proxying via :9000 (for faster cycle) and streaming into app/assets. But keep us posted and I'll certainly be interested.

Comment: Do you have an example of this kind of setup? I would like to see it in action. It's tempting to use current JavaScript technologies in Scala projects...

Comment: Not seen any publicly published. Google: browserify proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://github.com/nemoo/democratizer

This is an example project that uses play framework, scala, slick, mysql as a restful backend.

The client is a javascript single page application (SPA) written in react. It uses react router for client site routing and ES6 javascript.

The build process combines webpack and play activator which enables simple automatic browser refresh for server and client side code.